# Association Mapping or JOIN?

Tags: join, doctrine, associations, codeigniter-2

I'm new to Doctrine, and have only just gotten my mind around Entities, which are awesome.

I have two tables which contain information about messages.

Msg_links has a

- msg_ID field
- to_user
- is_read.

Msg_content has

- content_key
- msg_text
- from_user
- time_stamp.

When a message is generated in my application, if its from 1 user to 1 user, it generates content in both tables, and when displayed, msg_ID from Msg_links is relative to content_key.

If there were a message sent to 2 users, there would be only a single line in the msg_content table, but two lines in msg_links.   I hope that makes sense.

When my code displays mail, it needs to link the two tables.  I've done this before either with a VIEW in mysql, or with an inner join.

If I understand association mapping correctly, its rather like an entity of a join. Anywhere close?

So do I need to figure out association mapping and use that, or use querybuilder to make a join?

(note that I'm also using CodeIgniter2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN via Doctrine.

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("SELECT a.firstname, b.lastname FROM ORM\Testing\Firstnames a JOIN a.mylastname b WHERE b.id = $whichFamily");
```